# Bootstrap Table with Summary and Detail

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to use bootstrap tables to create a table that shows summary rows, and allows you to expand the summary to show the details by clicking a plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your table definition and write the detail code

```
<table id="yourTable" 
  data-detail-view="true
  data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter">
  ...

<script>
function detailFormatter(index, row) {
    var html = [];
    $.each(row, function (key, value) {
        html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>');
    });
    return html.join('');
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.